# How to extract RDD map from a line of space seperated values when the number of values are unknown?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My input file has space separated values with first one being the index. I am converting it into RDD map. I did for fixed number of values. Can you please suggest me how to do it if I don't know how many values are there in one line.

```
val vectors = inputfile.map(line => { val a = line.split(" "); (a(0))->(a(1), a(2), a(3))})
```

In the above line I am able to get the first four values into an array of the form `(1,(4,5,6))`.
What if I have something like `1 4 5 6 38 24` in the input file. How do I handle this?

Comment: Oh sorry. First day mistakes :p

Answer (score 1):

Use the `head` and `tail` methods:

```
val s = sc.parallelize(Seq("1 2 3 4 5", "2 1 3 4"))

s.map(line => {
     val fields = line.split(" ")
     Map(fields.head -> fields.tail)
}).collect
// res16: Array[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Array[String]]] = 
//        Array(Map(1 -> Array(2, 3, 4, 5)), Map(2 -> Array(1, 3, 4)))
```